# Why is this expression giving me a function body error?

Tags: scheme, racket, racket-student-languages

```
(define (subtract-1 n)
  (string-append "Number is: " (number->string n))
  (cond
    [(= n 0) "All done!"]
    [else (subtract-1(- n 1))]))
```

I keep getting the error: **define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part.** I'm not understanding why I'm getting this.

**NOTE TO SELF:** When using DrRacket, Setting the language to BSL may make Racket commands error at compile time.

Comment: Both `(string-append...)` and `(cond...)` are in the function body.

Comment: @dotnetN00b: yes, BSL is a restricted form of Racket where functions can only have one expression in their body.  The restriction is meant to help beginners who confuse side-effects with values: it forces you to write without side-effects.  If you want side effects, you need to be outside of BSL.  By the way, in the code above, there appears to be confusion: it looks like you want to _print_ a little logging message, but the code is actually _computing_ a logging message that won't be seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language you're using (BSL) only allows a single expression inside the body of a procedure, if there's more than one expression, you need to pack them inside a [`begin`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/begin.html).

Also notice that the `string-append` line is doing nothing, you should print it or accumulate it. Here's a possible solution with my recommendations in place:

```
(define (subtract-1 n)
  (begin
    (display (string-append "Number is: " (number->string n) "\n"))
    (cond
      [(= n 0) "All done!"]
      [else (subtract-1 (- n 1))])))
```

Even better, use the [`printf`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._printf%29%29) procedure for simplicity's sake:

```
(define (subtract-1 n)
  (begin
    (printf "~a ~s~n" "Number is:" n)
    (cond
      [(= n 0) "All done!"]
      [else (subtract-1 (- n 1))])))
```

Either way a sample execution looks like this:

```
(subtract-1 3)
=> Number is: 3
=> Number is: 2
=> Number is: 1
=> Number is: 0
=> "All done!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Racket documentation ([Sequencing](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/begin.html#%28part._.Effects_.Before__begin%29)) seems to suggest that you might need to use a begin expression for this to work, or it might be the missing space in `(subtract-1(- n 1))` between the function name and the parameter.

Also, you probably want to output the result of
`string-append` as it's not really doing anything as it is. Example to cover off all these points:

```
(define (subtract-1 n)
    (begin
        (write (string-append "Number is: " (number->string n)))
        (cond
            [(= n 0) "All done!"]
            [else (subtract-1 (- n 1))])))
```

Comment: "You may need to wrap the body up in extra parenthesis" <- that's bad advice, and totally incorrect!

Comment: @OscarLopez my bad. Tracked down Racket docs and updated accordingly.